# Microsoft Release Management : option to switch deployment order in a tag does not exist?

Tags: parallel-processing, tags, sequence, ms-release-management

On this [page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/11/what-s-new-in-release-management-for-vs-2013-update-4.aspx) it's described that
"*Now you can use tags with the servers in your Azure or on-premises (standard) environments. 
...
With tags you can also switch the deployment order from parallel to sequence.*"

See this picture:
[image: mrm tags parallel or sequence]

However in our version from MRM (ReleaseManagementConsole.exe ; 12.0.31101.0 ; Nov 1 2014) this option is not visible?

Is this a bug or is this configurable on the MRM server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature has been enabled only for vNext deployment sequences.

If you're creating an Agent based template you will not see the dropdown.

Comment: The release notes describe : "Now you can use tags with the servers in your Azure or on-premises (standard) environments.". So I assumed that this functionality is also working for normal/on-premises deployments.

Comment: You can deploy to an on-prem (standard) environment or azure environment using the vNext deployment sequence. And for doing this the tags sequence/parallel flip is enabled.

Comment: OK. Do you maybe have a link which describes the difference between "vNext" and "Agent Based"?

Comment: In short, for agent based templates - you'd need to set up deployment agents on the target machines. these agents will pull the tasks that are scheduled to run on them.
In the vNext flow, you do not need to install any agents on the target nodes, as it works by powershell remoting. You need to ensure the correct ports are opened on the target machine and you can remotely deploy to the machine.

Comment: An overall guide on RM - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217874.aspx
Agentless/vNext flow - https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/release/deploy-no-agents-vs